# Ubuntu 14.04 Intermittent Internet Disconnetion

Tags: internet, 14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (did a clean install from Ubuntu 13.10 recently) on my Desktop machine. Since the upgrade, my system has started showing strange behavior of intermittent disconnections in browsing. At that specific moment pinging the proxy server times out with more than 80% packet lost, or is unreachable. During this time the LAN connection is 'Connected', but starts to work only after I reset it.

*Example of Packet Loss*

```
user@user-desktop:~$ ping 192.168.0.51 PING 192.168.0.51
(192.168.0.51) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.51: icmp_seq=13 ttl=128 time=0.283 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.51: icmp_seq=14 ttl=128 time=0.275 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.51: icmp_seq=15 ttl=128 time=0.303 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.51: icmp_seq=16 ttl=128 time=0.272 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.51: icmp_seq=17 ttl=128 time=0.302 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.51: icmp_seq=18 ttl=128 time=0.509 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.51: icmp_seq=19 ttl=128 time=0.570 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.51: icmp_seq=20 ttl=128 time=0.211 ms ^?^C
--- 192.168.0.51 ping statistics ---
40 packets transmitted, 8 received, 80% packet loss, time 39100ms rtt
min/avg/max/mdev = 0.211/0.340/0.570/0.120 ms
```

*Example of Host Unreachable*

```
user@user-desktop:~$ ping 192.168.0.51
PING 192.168.0.51 (192.168.0.51) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=7 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=8 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=11 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=12 Destination Host Unreachable
--- 192.168.0.51 ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 0 received, +12 errors, 100% packet loss, time 12051ms
```

*Network Information*

```
user@user-desktop:~$ ifconfig
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:ac:c0:bb:67:d4 
      inet addr:192.168.1.206  Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.254.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::7aac:c0ff:febb:67d4/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:240643 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:223734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:25537053 (25.5 MB)  TX bytes:17135945 (17.1 MB)
      Interrupt:19 Memory:f0100000-f0120000

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback 
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:478 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:478 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:67030 (67.0 KB)  TX bytes:67030 (67.0 KB)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use  wifi with Wireless Router,I suggest you to change the Wireless Router's wireless channel to another unusual one. because the NIC driver of Ubuntu is imperfect

Comment: The problem is on Ethernet... not on wifi

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same behavior.  Solid connectivity while running 13.10 and previous builds.  Clean install of 14.4 and internet is very sporadic.

I did find that if I set up a continuous ping, I am able to browse somewhat reliably and the connection stays active.  Without the ping, it behaves as if the wireless shuts down completely until the next data request, then it has to renegotiate connection, creating severe lag.

In fact without the ping, I couldn't even run an apt-get update.

Not quite a solution, but it's helping me limp along until I can find an actual solution.

Comment: Russ Yes you are absolutely right. If ping is continuous, browsing behaves rightly.