# Internet trouble with Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: wireless, internet

Ever since I installed ubuntu on my desktop computer and using a WiFi Adapter, it keeps disconnecting, it says its connected, it happens randomly, I say about 30 minutes maybe to an hour it does it or so.

I use apache and people do connect to it, could that be the cause of internet loss? It keeps saying no internet but it says its connected and I have to reconnect for it to work again, it doesn't even pop up saying the internet got disconnected either, thats the weird part.

It's the latest Ubuntu. I would appreciate the help from anyone.

UPDATE: Its apache, when I reinstalled ubuntu (15 now), the WiFi started disconnecting and doing it again, before it would work fine.. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you getting something similar to what's described here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/456819/ubuntu-14-04-intermittent-internet-disconnetion

Comment: Nope, when I ping it on ubuntu it keeps pinging but when I do it on my windows computer it pings once and says request timed out, then if I reconnect the internet (it still says its connected but click the internet to reconnect), it works again?? (its also portforwarded)